# How to calculate VIF in python 3.6 with scipy 1.0.0?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to import

`from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor`

This is working fine upto Scipy 0.19.

But , with Python 3.6.3 ,it's failing due to unavailability of `ss` module in Scipy 1.0.0.

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in <module>()
     41 from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
     42 from scipy import stats
---> 43 from scipy.stats.stats import ss
     44 from scipy import optimize
     45 from scipy.stats import chi2

ImportError: cannot import name 'ss'
```

Can anyone please guide me how to do VIF analysis using Scipy1.0.0 ?

Comment: Which version of `statsmodels` are you using?  You can check with `import statsmodels; print(statsmodels.__version__)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ss` module is in `scipy.stats` not `scipy.stats.stats` as of [scipy 0.17](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ss.html#scipy.stats.ss). Also, it is deprecated, but you seem to have figured that out.

Second, in the current `linear_model.py` on [github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py), the `ss` package is no longer imported:

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from scipy import stats
from scipy import optimize
```

What version is your statsmodels? Sounds like you may need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

SciPy 1.0 requires `statsmodels >= 0.8  || None` (which just came out!).

Comment: I think you have that backwards, because SciPy (any version) does not require statsmodels at all.